# porting C++ library to .NET

Tags: c++, .net, c++11, c++-cli, shared-libraries

I have this simple library written in C++ (source code included)

```
struct MyStruct
{
    char message[ 90 ];
    int t;
};

enum MyEnum
{
    MY_ENUM_1, MY_ENUM_2
};

class IEvent 
{
public:
    virtual ~IEvent() {}

    virtual void event1( time_t ) = 0;
    virtual void event2( MyStruct s ) = 0;
    virtual void event3( MyEnum e ) = 0;
};

class Impl;

class MY_API Controller
{
public:
    Controller( IEvent* eventListener );
    ~Controller();

    void addListener( IEvent* eventListener );
    void removeListener( IEvent* eventListener );

    void f1( MyEnum e );
    void f2();

private:
    Impl* mImpl;
};
```

The code is implemented in C++11. I need to port this code to .NET.

I thought that a good choice can be C++/CLI but after lots of google I didn't find nothing.

Does someone know how to port this code in C++/CLI? I am able to build all the library in C++/CLI but the library doesn't export any symbols.

**Edit1** 
The library is huge and a re-write in other language is too expensive.

Comment: If you want to be able to use this just like native C# object, you need to create `public ref class` wrappers. In that case, you might want to just build the library as "normal", and then build a separate interface layer in C++/CLI.

Comment: In this case wrapping Controller is easy. But what about IEvent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to port this code to .NET, to be used in other .NET languages, such as C#, then you're going to want to re-work how this library does things. **Regardless of what language you choose to implement in**, if your goal is to be consumed by other .NET languages, you should switch to the .NET paradigms.

For example: currently, you have an abstract class named `IEvent`. You could create a .NET interface named `IEvent`, and implement it the same way, but that's not how you do things in .NET. Instead, you'd want to define 3 delegate types, and have your Controller class define 3 events of those delegate types. Instead of `addListener` and `removeListener`, each of the events would have add and remove methods (accessed through `+=` and `-=`).

```
delegate void Event1Handler(object sender, DateTime data);
delegate void Event2Handler(object sender, MyStruct data);
delegate void Event3Handler(object sender, MyEnum data);

public class EventExample_Controller
{
    public event Event1Handler Event1;
    public event Event2Handler Event2;
    public event Event3Handler Event3;
}
```

As for the language to use, my initial response would be "C# if you can, C++/CLI if you have to". You haven't said what this library does, it may not be easy, or even possible, to do it in C#. But if you can do it in C#, then you'll get the benefits that language provides: Many of the benefits have equivalents in C++/CLI (e.g., linq query syntax can be represented with regular syntax, extension methods can be called as regular static methods, everything using the `async` keyword can be done with Tasks and a crapload of state variables), but some are C# only (e.g., having one assembly that works in 32-bit and 64-bit mode).

As for your try to compile the library as-is in C++/CLI, you need to mark the classes as managed classes. Change the classes to `public ref class`, and the enums to `public enum class`, and that'll create them as managed. Your next step will be to switch all your pointers to your own classes from unmanaged pointers (`*`) to managed references (`^`), and use `gcnew` instead of `new` for them.